# lack of knowledge to do it the best way with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a system where I need to transfer a product from one store to another.

So, I already have my product model... and I already have my store model.

Now, I need to put together a transfer model which I thought of putting together as follows.

```
  Transfer:
    date:date
    quantity:integer
    user:references
    type:integer (manual/by_system)(i will create an Enum here)
    product:references

    source_store_id:references
    destiny_store_id:references
```

My doubt is for these two columns. it's correct to make this way? (sorce_store_id and destiny_store_id)

How i'll implement this in model?
transfer model:

```
  has_one :store
  belongs_to :store
```

it's correct?

Comment: Titles of questions are intended to give some idea of what the question is about. Could you imagine a book entitled, "Lack of Knowledge Was a Problem When Writing this Book"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the transfer model you'd have

```
belongs_to :source_store, class_name: "Store"
belongs_to :destiny_store, class_name: "Store
```

To reference it the other direction you'd also need a has_many on the `store.rb`

```
has_many :source_transfers, class_name: "Transfer", foreign_key: :source_store_id
has_many :destiny_transfers, class_name: "Transfer", foreign_key: :destiny_store_id
```

Also, you correctly have `user:references` in the schema setup but the for the stores, makes sure you dont include the `_id`

```
source_store:references
destiny_store:references
```

And in the migration itself it might look like:

```
create_table :transfers do |t|
  # ...
  t.references :source_store, foreign_key: {to_table: :stores}
  t.references :destiny_store, foreign_key: {to_table: :stores}
end
```